# RecyclerView SCROLL_STATE_IDLE is being called late

Tags: android-layout, scroll, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, onscrolllistener

On RecyclerView `addOnScrollListener` the property `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` takes time to get called at end of the item size and when scrolled up to the top of the RecyclerView. But it works fine in middle of the scrolling.

The root view of the layout is CoordinatorLayout.

Answer (score 5):

Having the same issue, the only workaround I've found is to send a **stopScroll()** whenever the RecyclerView gets a **SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING**, though not the ideal solution. Probably would be better to detect if it has reached the top or bottom edge, taking into account the scrolling direction, and then call stopScroll():

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(final int state)
{
    super.onScrollStateChanged(state);

    if (state == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING)
    {
        this.stopScroll();
    }
}
```

**Update**

This issue seems to be a bug in the support library, though it was reported as fixed its clear that the problem still exists, so hopefully we should see an adequate solution in the future:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66996774

Comment: Good workaround thanks. I personally had to do `recyclerView.stopNestedScroll(1)` instead of `this.stopScroll()` and it works fine. Another remark that was not obvious when reading your solution: visually it works just fine, it doesn't abruptly stop the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke stopScroll() when your recyclerview has been reached to to bottom.
I think Since it's support library version up, velocity is calulated and it makes delay a little.