# Is SCROLL_STATE_IDLE is a good parameter to detect scroll in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to know idle state of recyclerview to do something and use this check:
`recyclerView.getScrollState() == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` but it sounds doesn't work correctly all the times. What should I do?

Comment: @pskink It sounds recyclerview makes mistake in detection of idle state when I use `log` in this condtion.

Comment: Do you want **callbacks** regarding scroll events in `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @pskink Dosen't detect the idel state.

Comment: @Jee Vankhede I want to know idle state. Means when doesn't scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**RecyclerView.OnScrollListener**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener) for checking if `Recycleriew` is on **IDLE_STATE**.

You can check state of `RecyclerView` using this method:

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    // check your recycler view state here with newState.
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind, the support version of the RecyclerView appears to register this state late, as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48302137/461982.